# Method parameter not being recognized

Tags: c#

My code looks like this:

```
void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && questCount == 6)
  {

    Score(sumFinal);

  }
}

public int Score(int sumFinal)
{
sumFinal = dCount - rCount;
return sumFinal;
}
```

Visual Studio tells me sumFinal doesn't exist in the current context.
How can I return sumFinal within Update() successfully? Am I understanding parameters correctly?

Additional Question:

Below further down the Score() function, I set text to certain values:

```
public int Score(int sumFinal) 
{ 
sumFinal = dCount - rCount;
return sumFinal; 

if (sumFinal == 5 && questCount >= 5) 
{ 
labelText.text = "results"; 
}
}
```

When calling this function in Update(), is there a way I can run both the if statement and the sumFinal subtraction equation separately? In short, how do I segment the function, and call only specific parts of it? Should the return type be set to void?

Comment: The problem is exactly as described in the error message. You are using the identifier `sumFinal`, but no such identifier exists in that context. See e.g. duplicate and numerous other Stack Overflow questions addressing the exact error message. Also see the language documentation, especially https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio tells me sumFinal doesn't exist in the current context. How can I return sumFinal within Update() successfully? Am I understanding parameters correctly?

The method `Score` looks great! However, when you call it `Score(sumFinal);` you need to make sure that you're passing a value to the method. In your case you may have forgotten to have a field with the value at the top of the class.

> is there a way I can run both the if statement and the sumFinal subtraction equation separately?

Sure! What you could do, since you don't actually give `Score` any value when you call it, you can remove that parameter and just return the value that it calculates.

The we could separate updating the text to another method called `UpdateTextBox()` that takes the result of `Score()` to determine if it should change the text or not

```cs
public class YourUnityClass : MOnoBehaviour
{
    int questCount = 0;

    int sumFinal = 0; // make sure that if you need to access this variable between methods that this field exists

    int dCount = 0;

    int rCount = 0;

    public TextMesh labelText;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && questCount == 6)
        {
            // calculate and save the score
            sumFinal = Score();
            
            // check the score, and update the text if necessary
            UpdateTextBox(sumFinal);
        }
    }

    public int Score()
    {
        // calculate the score
        return dCount - rCount;
    }

    public void UpdateTextBox(int sumFinal)
    {
        // check to see if the score is high enough to change
        // the text
        if (sumFinal == 5 && questCount >= 5)
        {
            labelText.text = "results";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not encourage users when they post [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: Thanks! That brings up some very valuable information, I'll keep that in mind. I appreciate it.

Comment: It works! Thank you for helping a newbie programmer